# can i decompose the image deblurring model?

Tags: image-processing

hello i am recently working in image de-blurring, i just want to know that can i break the standard image degradation model {for an image of traffic signal where different vehicles are moving in different direction}

```
   g(x,y) = H[f(x,y)] + n(x,y)
```

like that

```
   g1(x,y) = H1[f1(x,y)] + n(x,y) ;

   g2(x,y) = H2[f2(x,y)] + n(x,y) ;

   g3(x,y) = H3[f3(x,y)] + n(x,y) ;

     .....................
     .....................
     .....................
     .....................

   gm(x,y) = Hm[fm(x,y)] + n(x,y)
```

here i am assuming that the whole image is degraded by different degradation functions, and same noise is added to different part of noise.

here f1(x,y) + f2(x,y) ......... + fm(x,y) = f(x,y).

Please suggest the correct concept. and tell me if i am going on wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer of this question with slight changes...

we can decompose the image degradation model 
     **g(x,y) = H[f(x,y)] + n(x,y)**
as 
g(x,y) = H[f1(x,y)] + H[f2(x,y)] + H[f3(x,y)] ..... + H[fn(x,y)]

using the concept of Linearity if

g(x,y) = H[k1xf1(x,y) + k2xf2(x,y)]
       = k1xH[f1(x,y)]+ k2xH[f2(x,y)]

and if k1 = k2 = 1 then
g(x,y) = H[f1(x,y)]+ H[f2(x,y)]

similarly we can get the following form

**g(x,y) = H[f1(x,y)] + H[f2(x,y)] + H[f3(x,y)] ..... + H[fn(x,y)]**